# Mathematical Fallacy - The $17$ camels Problem.

Tags: fake-proofs, paradoxes

So the Problem goes like this :-

- An old man had $17$ camels . He had $3$ sons and the man had decided to give each son a property with his camels.
- Unfortunately however, the man dies, and in his last will he says that his $1$st son will get $1/2$ of the total camels, his $2$nd son will get $1/3$ on the total camels, and his $3$rd son will get $1/9$ of the total camels.
- This looks like a major problem , because $17$ is not divisible by neither of $2,3,9$ ; and it looks impossible to divide $17$ camels like that .

The Solution however, is very interesting and goes like this :

- First bring another camel ( from a camel owner ) and add it to this group of $17$ camels. The total no. of camels now becomes $18$ .
- Also $18$ is divisible by each of $2,3,9$; so the $1$st son gets $9$ camels, the $2$nd son gets $6$ camels, and the third son gets $2$ camels.
- Miraculously , we get $9 + 6 + 2 = 17$ camels , hence the extra camel that was brought before can be returned back to the owner.

After doing this problem , I suppose that there is some mathematical fallacy involved here. When we had $17$ camels , it was impossible to divide them. However after adding $1$ extra camel , everything divides very nicely among the sons as well as the extra camel could be returned. How is this working ?.

I am posting this Problem so that I can get some opinions or discussions about this Problem.

Comment: $1/2+1/3+1/9=17/18$

Comment: Yes it's true. $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{9}$ do equal $\frac{17}{18}$.  But how is the solutions working ?

Comment: I don't see any fallacy here; as Integrand says the explanation is $1/2+1/3+1/9=17/18$.

Comment: What I see going on here is that some numbers have many factors and some numbers do not!

Comment: The solution works exactly as you see it : the ratio doesn't add to $1$, so there is a wise extra person who receives the remaining $\frac 1{18}$ of the camels. If we want the trick to work, we want to make sure that the extra person gives as many camels as he gets back, so the total number of camels after his giving, should be $18$ times the number of camels he gives. That works and provides the number of camels he gives, and furthermore it so happens that every other person also gets an integer number of camels. The choice of numbers is special.

Comment: @астонвіллатересалисбон , true . Your comment do makes sense to me .

Comment: Let us change the numbers, for example : suppose there are two sons, one son had to get $\frac 14$ and another $\frac 16$. Then, the total of these is $\frac{5}{12}$, so the wise man would have to provide $\frac{7}{12}$ of the total number of camels after $17$. That gives $\frac{7(17+x)}{12} = x$, which gives $x$ non-integral, so the whole thing fails here because the wise man cannot give a non-integral number of camels. We can come up with sufficient conditions for it to work. Can I write an answer?

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/q/271608

Comment: Honestly... I've never understood this puzzle.  The guy wills *his* camels in proportions, and not some other other number of camels in proportions.  So I don't understand why this should be considered a "solution"....  Consider the following.  A man dies leaving a 10,000 dollar estate $\frac 1{10}$ to one son and $\frac 9{10}$ to the other.  The son doesn't think it is fair. A wise man tosses in 1,990,000 dollars and ans so one son gets 200,000 and the other gets 1,800,000. Then the sons give the man $195,000$ and 1,795,000 so both have 5000. That's crap but why is it any different?

Comment: The question seems to be that a set of proportions don't divide one number evenly but will divide some other number evenly and .... well, so what... What if no man came by but the brothers just decided "heck, lets just agree to round it". Why is that not a solution?  Or when the wise man took is camel back oldest son said "No way! I'm giving you back $\frac 9{17}$s of a camel but my brothers are only giving you $\frac  2{17}$ and $\frac 6{17}$ a camel!  I insist we split the camel fairly and each give you $\frac 13$ a camel!"  In what we did the wise man solve that problem?

Comment: ""so there is a wise extra person who receives the remaining 118 of the camels"  But not in the same proportion as their inheritences!  The first son should pay back $\frac 12$ the camel but instead pays back $\frac {9}{17}$s of the camel. The second son should pay back $\frac 13$ of the camel but pays back $\frac {6}{17}$ and the third son should pay back $\frac 19$ of the camel but pays back $\frac {2}{17}$ of the camel.  This solves nothing.

Comment: I suppose one could say the will *cant* be fulfilled as it is contradictory.  It only accounts for $\frac {17}{18}$s of the mans camels.

Comment: "I am posting this Problem so that I can get some opinions or discussions about this Problem." Getting opinions and starting discussions is exactly what this website is **not** meant for.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson I already mentionned this question...

Comment: It is in fact rather a joke solution than an actual solution. I agree fleablood. Similar to the "proof" that every natural number is interesting (If not, there is a smallest number not interesting making it interesting)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way the puzzle is told there is supposedly no fallacy and this *is* supposed to be the solution. The division doesn't add up to $100\%$ so there's nothing wrong with there being a camel left over.  And the sons get $\frac 12, \frac 13, \frac 19$ of $18$ camels so the division worked out evenly.  And every version of the puzzle I've ever heard claims this is the legitimate solution.

Which drives me nuts because this obviously *isn't* a solution.  The first son got $\frac 12$ of $18$ camels but that *wasn't* what the will speculated.  The will speculates that he should get $\frac 12$ of $17$ camels.  He ended up with half a camel more!  Likewise the second son ended up with $\frac 13$ of a camel more and the third son with $\frac 19$ of a camel more.

Which makes sense as the will only speculated what to do with $16 \frac 1{18}$ of the camels and not what to do with the remaining $\frac {17}{18}$ of a camel.  But they didn't need the "wise man" for that.  They could have simply said: Son 1 gets $8\frac 12$ camel. Son 2 gets $5 \frac 23$ of a camel.  Son 3 gets $1\frac 89$ of a camel.  There is $\frac {17}{18}$ of a camel left over.  Let's make an agreement among ourself that Son 1, Son 2,and Son 3 get an extra $\frac 12, \frac 13, \frac 19$ camel to make it even.  As we each get more than the will speculated we should all be happy.

But I don't think that "solves" any problem.

And it the end the sons *didn't* end up with $16\frac 1{18}$ camels divide in $\frac 12, \frac 13$ and $\frac 19$ as the will stipulated.  They ended up with $17$ camels dived $\frac 9{17},\frac {6}{17}, \frac 2{17}$ as the will did *not* stipulated.

So in *MY* opinion.... I *hate* this stupid puzzle and think it is false and its fallacy is....

.......

The mathematical fallacy is the are returning the camel in disproportion to their inheritance.

The 1st son who inherits $\frac 12$ the camels should be borrowing and returning $\frac 12$ a camel.  He is borrowing and returning $\frac {9}{17}$ of a camel. The 2nd son who inherits $\frac 13$ is returning $\frac {6}{17}$s of a camel and not $\frac 13$ and the 3rd son who inherits $\frac 19$ is return $\frac 2{17}$s of a camel and not $\frac 19$.

The father's will divided *his* camels.  Not his camels plus some other number of camels and then return the borrowed camels back.

Suppose the extra man instead of having $1$ camel had $37$ camels.  So that makes $37+17= 54$ camels.  The first son gets $27$ and the second gets $18$ and the third gets $6$.  The wise man gets back $3$ camels.  Then the older son give him $21$ back and keeps $6$ and the second son gives him $12$ back and keeps $6$ and the third son gives him $1$ back and keeps $5$. so the wise man gets back his $37$ camels and we end up with the sons having $5,6,6$ camels each.

Problem solved?

Answer (score -1):

So because the ratios don't add to 100 percent of the camels and the will remains silent on the last 1/18 of the camels.

LCD of 1/2 and 1/3 and 1/9 is 18.

- son 1 gets 9/18 of camels
- son 2 gets 6/18 of camels
- son 3 gets 2/18 of camels
- nobody gets 1/18 of camels (not assigned by the will!)

Pretend son 4 was supposed to get the 1/18 not assigned by the ratio, bringing us to 100% of camels assigned.

So,  what really happens is that

- son 1 "steals" 1/2 camels from the unassigned 1/18
- son 2 "steals" 1/3 camels from the unassigned 1/18
- son 3 "steals" 1/9 camels from the unassigned 1/18
- son 4 looses out on his 1/18 camels!

The solution distributes an unassigned fractional camel.