# Can't understand the solution of this INMO problem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, contest-math, pigeonhole-principle

In any set of $181$ square integers, prove that one can always find a subset of $19$ numbers, sum of whose elements is divisible by $19$.

Someone on [AOPS](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h54868p341785):

> Direct checking shows that any square is $0,1,4,9,16,6,17,11,7,5 \mod
> [19].$ Thus there are exactly $10$ distinct possibilities. From the
> pigeon-hole principle, since you used $181$ numbers at least one of
> the class contains at least $19$ of your squares. Adding these $19$
> squares from the same class leads to the result.

Can anyone explain me this solution, or some other?

Thanks!

PS: This question is from Indian National Mathematical Olympiad 1994, Problem 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there were at most $18$ of each of those $10$ square congruences being used in the set, then the maximum number of elements in the set would be $18 \times 10 = 180$. However, since there are $181$ elements, this means that, by the pigeon-hole principle, there must be at least one congruence, say $r$, used at least $19$ times. As the solution states, adding these $19$ elements will give a sum with a remainder of $19r$, i.e., a value divisible by $19$.

Note that, in general, you actually only need just a set of $2 \times 19 - 1 = 37$ integers, without any particular restrictions on their congruences, for there to be a subset of $19$ of them that sum to a multiple of $19$. For more information about these types of problems, please see [Proving that among any $2n - 1$ integers, there's always a subset of $n$ which sum to a multiple of $n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3754764/602049).

Comment: Oh thank you very much. Silly of me to not get the simple point.

Comment: @AkshatVats You're welcome. I've quite often found I've had trouble initially understanding some fairly simple concept as well.